# Hexadecimal number stored in str format is stored back in hexadecimal format

Tags: python, encryption, hex, key

I tried to create a list (the key I am trying to create) with 32 hexadecimal numbers in the function below. The result is:

```py
def make_key(str : str) : 
    base = []
    res = []
    for i in str :
        base.append(i)
    for i in base :
        res.append(hex(ord(i)))
    return res

key = make_key('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
print(key)
```

result is

```
['0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61', '0x61']
```

Is there a way to convert this string formatted hexadecimal to hexadecimal format only?

To sum it up:

I've tried things like:

```py
def make_key(str : str) : 
    base = []
    res = []
    for i in str :
        base.append(i)
    for i in base :
        res.append(hex(ord(i)))
    return res

key = make_key('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
print(key)
```

I hope the result is something like this:

```
[0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61,0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61,0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61]
```

Comment: Your result is a list of integers. If you print that you will get [97, 97] etc because that's the default for integers

Comment: `hex()` [converts an integer number to a lowercase hexadecimal string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex). If you are just interested in a list of int, leave out the `hex()`. Alternatively, you could display the whole list as a string, e.g. `"[0x61, 0x61, 0x61"`

Comment: @Fred Thanks for your reply. Could you please tell me how to store this in a variable as a list?

Comment: @glasshope You already have a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a list of integers, printing that list will show the values (unsurprisingly) as base 10 integers.

If this is just a formatting exercise then:

```
def make_key(s):
    return [hex(ord(c)) for c in s]

print('[' + ', '.join(make_key('aaaa')) + ']')
```

What's happening here is that we construct a string to look like a Python list which gives this output:

```
[0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61]
```